# Creating a JSON from an ArrayList of stings in Android

Tags: android, json

I have an array of string:

```
a = ["bob","jade","smith"]
```

I want to convert this to a JSON output like the following in my Android application, this data needs to be sent to the server.

```
{"names":["bob","jade","smith"]}
```

Plz help.

I have tried this:

```
Gson abs = new Gson();
String data = abs.toJson(a);
JSONObject jObjectType = new JSONObject();
jObjectType.put("names",data);
data=jObjectType.toString();
```

This is my output on the log:

```
{"names":"[\"bob\",\"jade\",\"smith\"]"}
```

Comment: so now just clean string from backslashes and you got it.

Comment: @Sajmon [Please see this post on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134)

Comment: I got the solution, just create a java class with all the required keys as its member variables. Then pass the object to the toJason() function, thus we get the required jason string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray names = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(a));
JSONObject jsonToSend = new JSONObject();
jsonToSend.put("names", names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), this library allows you to convert any object to JSON format, and back to the same object once you receive the JSON.

```
(Serialization)
Gson gson = new Gson();
int[] values = { 1 };
gson.toJson(values);       ==> prints [1]

(Deserialization)
int one = gson.fromJson("1", int.class);
Integer one = gson.fromJson("1", Integer.class);
Long one = gson.fromJson("1", Long.class);
Boolean false = gson.fromJson("false", Boolean.class);
String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);
String anotherStr = gson.fromJson("[\"abc\"]", String.class);
```